# Need Help with animation gallery in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I been trying to create a gallery in Flash with different movie clips.

```
Timeline
-back button
-next button
-stop button
-play button 
-Main Movie
 (these are inside Main Movie)
 --Animation 1
 --Animation 2
 --Animation 3
```

I have the animations set up in Main Movie with instance name and frame names like "Animation 1".  I got it to play and stop, but I can't go back and forth through each animations with the back and next buttons.  What's the right way I can pull this off?

---Update 8-20-2010

I got it to work, but with a tiny bug. Whenever I click the next or back buttons it goes to the first frame name then the other.  I did a trace and I found it counting "ad-1, ad-2, ad-3, etc.." or "ad1, ad2, ad3, etc.."

```
var currentAnimationIndex:int;
var currentAnimation:int;
var animeOstart:Number = 1;
var animeOend:Number = 3;

function playAnimation(frameIndex:int):void 
{ 
   var frameName:String = "ad" + frameIndex.toString();
   trace(frameName)
   ads.gotoAndPlay(frameName);
   ads.movie.gotoAndPlay(1);

   currentAnimationIndex = frameIndex; 
} 

function playBack(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
   --currentAnimationIndex; 

   if(currentAnimationIndex < animeOstart) 
      currentAnimation == 1; 

  playAnimation(currentAnimationIndex); 
} 

function playNext(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
   ++currentAnimationIndex; 

   if(currentAnimationIndex > animeOend) 
      currentAnimation == 3; 

  playAnimation(currentAnimationIndex); 
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details? Please tell me the behavior you expect and the behavior that you actually get

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm stuck at the doctors office and sick like no tomorrow.  What I was trying to do is when you the flash movie start the first animation starts up and if you click on the next button you go to the second animation and when you get to the last animation it goes back to the first animation, the same for the back on in the reverse.  I hope that help. Again sorry if I didn't word it right.  I been feeling ill.  :(

Comment: sorry, i'm only seeing your comment now! i've edited the code so it should work as expected but I see you also found a solution. sorry about the delay in replying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it in AS3!!!!

```
b_back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevSection);
b_next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextSection);

function nextSection(event:MouseEvent):void {

    var thisLabel:String = ads.currentLabel; // gets current frame label as string
    var thisLabelNum:String = thisLabel.replace("ad", ""); // cuts the leading letters off of the number
    var curNumber:Number = Number(thisLabelNum); // converts that string number to a real number
    if (curNumber < 3) {
        var nextNum:Number = curNumber + 1; // adds 1 to the number so we can go to next frame label
        ads.gotoAndPlay("ad" + nextNum); // This allows us to go to the next frame label
    }else if(curNumber >= 3){
        ads.gotoAndPlay("ad" + 1); // This allows us to go to the next frame label
    }
}

function prevSection(event:MouseEvent):void {

    var thisLabel:String = ads.currentLabel; // gets current frame label as string
    var thisLabelNum:String = thisLabel.replace("ad", ""); // cuts the leading letters off of the number
    var curNumber:Number = Number(thisLabelNum); // converts that string number to a real number
    var prevNum:Number = curNumber - 1; // subtracts 1 from the number so we can go to next frame label
    ads.gotoAndPlay("ad" + prevNum); // This allows us to go to the previous frame label*/
    if (curNumber == 1) {
        ads.gotoAndPlay("ad" + 3); // This allows us to go to the next frame label
    }

}
```

found it from this site.  http://www.developphp.com/Flash_tutorials/show_tutorial.php?tid=161

Answer (score 1):

You should place the following code on the main Timeline , where the buttons are. I've given the instance name "main" to your Main MovieClip.

```
  var currentAnimationIndex:int;

  public function playAnimation(frameIndex:int):void
  {
       var frameName:String = "Animation " + frameIndex.toString();
       main.gotoAndStop(frameName);

       currentAnimationIndex = frameIndex;
  }

  public function playBack(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
       --currentAnimationIndex;

       if(currentAnimationIndex < 1)
          currentAnimation == 3;

      playAnimation(currentAnimationIndex);
  }

  public function playNext(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
       ++currentAnimationIndex;

       if(currentAnimationIndex > 3)
          currentAnimation == 1;

      playAnimation(currentAnimationIndex);
  }
```

Create a variable that registers the current animation and decrement it or increment it to go back or to play the next animation. Assign the relevant function to the button with a MouseEvent listener. Here I have used 1 & 3 but you could have a couple of variables, minAnimIndex & maxAnimIndex.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm trying it out now. The only question I have is when I assign the variable for the current animation, your talking about having it in "Main Movie" right?

Comment: Yes it should be at the same level as the animation , if not you would have to do something similar to this:

      instanceName.gotoAndStop(frameName);

meaning calling the method from the MovieClip where the animations are

Comment: I think I got it so far.  I put 'currentAnimationIndex' and 'currentAnimation' in the animation of the movie, but I keep getting this error in the script.

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: playNext.